# Some website is scraping SE questions and answers. Is SE doing something about it?

Tags: support

I got a pingback on my blog a non-SE site (link removed) and apparently they just copy all the questions, answers and even comments, including the embedded links.

What does SE do about it?

Comment: By linking to this site you are helping their SEO. Removing the link for now since SE already knows it.

Answer (score 3):

They are violating the [attribution rules](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) by not acknowledging either the original author or StackExchange - while they do link to the original question, I don't think that's enough.

As [described on StackExchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/132930), I've reported them directly to StackExchange, and they've replied as follows:

---

Thank you for reporting this content. I've passed the information along to the person at our company who handles such issues. It's the diligence of users like you that helps us stay valuable!

Please note, bringing these sites into compliance (or getting them to no longer serve our content) is often a long and arduous process. You may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're working on it.

Thank you again,

The Stack Overflow Team.